# Adding two matrices and maintain the structure

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I want to add/merge two graphs in form of adjacency matrices and take care of the structure.

The first graph looks like this:

[image]

The related adjacency matrix is:

```
 0. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 0. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 0. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 0.
```

The second graph looks like this:

[image]

The related adjacency matrix is:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.] 
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.] 
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.] 
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Now I thought, I can pad the first matrix and simply add the first matrix to the second. But the result is not what i desired.

So my question is, how can I merge/add two adjacency matrices and taking care/maintain of their structure ... ?

My desired outcome should look like this:

[image]

Any idea would be helpful :).

Comment: Your first graph has 4 vertices but the matrix you shown is 3x4, not 4x4. The second graph has 16 vertices but the matrix you showed is 15x16, not 16x16. Maybe you're missing a row?

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake ... i forgot to draw the line :). this does not solve the problem :)

Comment: "Now I thought, I can pad the first matrix and simply add the first matrix to the second. But the result is not what i desired."  Why? What's wrong with the result? Note that it would help a lot if you wrote the indices of the vertices on the drawing of the graphs, so we can see which row and column of the matrix corresponds to which vertex in the drawing.

Comment: Hi - welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately it's not clear what outcome you expected.  If you can give that, I think we can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the sort of thing you might be after. The trick is to use `nx.compose` to merge the two graphs together.

Set up first graph:

```
import networkx as nx

adjmat1 = np.array([[0., 1., 1., 1.],
                      [1., 0., 1., 1.],
                      [1., 1., 0., 1.],
                      [1., 1., 1., 0.]])

adjmat1_df = pd.DataFrame(adjmat1)
node_labels = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)]
adjmat1_df.columns = node_labels
adjmat1_df.index = node_labels

G1 = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(adjmat1_df)

pos = {(x,y):(y,-x) for x,y in G1.nodes()}
nx.draw(G1, pos=pos, 
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        with_labels=True,
        node_size=600)
```

[image: First graph]

Set up second graph (I've gone for a quick grid setup but you can use your second adjacency matrix to create a graph as in the first step):

```
# Following @yatu's SO answer for plotting https://stackoverflow.com/a/62161953/6386471

G2 = nx.grid_2d_graph(4,4)
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
pos = {(x,y):(y,-x) for x,y in G2.nodes()}
nx.draw(G2, pos=pos, 
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        with_labels=True,
        node_size=600)
```

[image: Second graph]

Use `nx.compose` to combine the graphs:

```
H = nx.compose(G1,G2)
pos = {(x,y):(y,-x) for x,y in H.nodes()}
nx.draw(H, pos=pos, 
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        with_labels=True,
        node_size=600)
```

[image: Combined graph]

Comment: Thank you so much! My problem was, that i forgot to give the graph the right node_labels and indices :)