# Grid visualization of a graph from adjacency list

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a program that generated the following adjacency list:
The data represent a 2D grid graph of size 4 by 14 but every node is not necessarily connected to all its neighbors.

My adjacency list is:

```
list_ng2d={(0, 0): [(0, 1)],
 (0, 1): [(0, 2), (0, 0)],
 (0, 2): [(1, 2), (0, 3), (0, 1)],
 (0, 3): [(0, 4), (0, 2)],
 (0, 4): [(1, 4), (0, 5), (0, 3)],
 (0, 5): [(0, 6), (0, 4)],
 (0, 6): [(0, 7), (0, 5)],
 (0, 7): [(0, 8), (0, 6)],
 (0, 8): [(0, 9), (0, 7)],
 (0, 9): [(1, 9), (0, 10), (0, 8)],
 (0, 10): [(0, 11), (0, 9)],
 (0, 11): [(1, 11), (0, 12), (0, 10)],
 (0, 12): [(0, 13), (0, 11)],
 (0, 13): [(0, 12)],
 (1, 0): [(1, 1)],
 (1, 1): [(1, 2), (1, 0)],
 (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 1)],
 (1, 3): [(1, 4), (1, 2)],
 (1, 4): [(0, 4), (1, 5), (1, 3)],
 (1, 5): [(1, 6), (1, 4)],
 (1, 6): [(2, 6), (1, 7), (1, 5)],
 (1, 7): [(1, 8), (1, 6)],
 (1, 8): [(2, 8), (1, 9), (1, 7)],
 (1, 9): [(0, 9), (1, 10), (1, 8)],
 (1, 10): [(1, 11), (1, 9)],
 (1, 11): [(0, 11), (1, 12), (1, 10)],
 (1, 12): [(1, 13), (1, 11)],
 (1, 13): [(1, 12)],
 (2, 0): [(2, 1)],
 (2, 1): [(2, 2), (2, 0)],
 (2, 2): [(3, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1)],
 (2, 3): [(2, 4), (2, 2)],
 (2, 4): [(3, 4), (2, 5), (2, 3)],
 (2, 5): [(2, 6), (2, 4)],
 (2, 6): [(1, 6), (2, 7), (2, 5)],
 (2, 7): [(2, 8), (2, 6)],
 (2, 8): [(1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 7)],
 (2, 9): [(3, 9), (2, 10), (2, 8)],
 (2, 10): [(2, 11), (2, 9)],
 (2, 11): [(3, 11), (2, 12), (2, 10)],
 (2, 12): [(2, 13), (2, 11)],
 (2, 13): [(2, 12)],
 (3, 0): [(3, 1)],
 (3, 1): [(3, 2), (3, 0)],
 (3, 2): [(2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 1)],
 (3, 3): [(3, 4), (3, 2)],
 (3, 4): [(2, 4), (3, 5), (3, 3)],
 (3, 5): [(3, 6), (3, 4)],
 (3, 6): [(3, 7), (3, 5)],
 (3, 7): [(3, 8), (3, 6)],
 (3, 8): [(3, 9), (3, 7)],
 (3, 9): [(2, 9), (3, 10), (3, 8)],
 (3, 10): [(3, 11), (3, 9)],
 (3, 11): [(2, 11), (3, 12), (3, 10)],
 (3, 12): [(3, 13), (3, 11)],
 (3, 13): [(3, 12)]}
```

I am trying to draw this graph to visualize the form of the graph (I drew it by hand for small instances on paper)

What I tried so far is to make a networkx instance and draw it, but I could not get it to draw things properly, it is adding edges that are not in the list

```
H = nx.Graph(list_ng2d)
# nx.draw(H, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,M)

# plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
pos=dict()
for node,val in list_ng2d.items():
#     print(f" {node} ngbrs {val}")
    for ngbr in val:
        pos[node]=ngbr
# pos = {(x,y):(y,-x) for x,y in G.nodes()}
# G.remove_edges_from([(0,13),(1,13)])
# nx.draw(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'),
#         node_color='lightgreen', 
#         with_labels=True,
#         node_size=100)
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)

labels = dict(((i, j), i *M + (j)) for i, j in H.nodes())  #M=14

pos = {y:x for x,y in labels.items()}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 100)
labels.items()
```

What I get

[image]

What I am trying to draw (the image is rotated compared to networkx)
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction or give ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `nx.grid_2d_graph` is indeed pretty useful to do what you want to do.
As you can see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109590/how-to-graph-nodes-on-a-grid-in-networkx) SO answer you can use it to get the positions of your nodes. You can then simply draw your graph.

See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H = nx.Graph(list_ng2d) #create graph from adjacency matrix
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(4,14) #create a grid graph but only use it to get the label positions 

pos = {(x,y):(y,-x) for x,y in G.nodes()} #get the positions of the nodes from G

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(H, pos=pos,node_size=200,node_color='w',edgecolors='k') #plot nodes
nx.draw_networkx_edges(H, pos=pos) #plot edges
plt.box(False)
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your input data is in a very inconvenient form, so it has to be preprocessed.

```
LOOP over input to find min x, max x, min y, max y
Create vertices at grid points in range min x, max x, min y, max y
LOOP over input to create edges between vertices
```

Now you have an actual adjacency list which cam be processed in a straightforward way. The trick is to draw the vertices AFTER the edges, so the edges appear to stop at the vertex boundaries.

```
LOOP over edges
   Draw line from source vertex location to destination vertex location
LOOP over vertices
   Draw filled circle at vertex location
```

I have posted a C++ implementation of this at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/c30b5e812a63fd234370f719a9a568ba